Steps to promote a logical replica in PostgreSQL
If I want to promote a logical replica in PostgreSQL, do I have to do any additional setup besides stopping the replication?
I think I can see is sequence values are not replicated so I have do something like pg_dump -d dbname -U username -t '*_id_seq' > seq.sql to dump the sequence and copy to the logical replica to be promoted. Is there a better way to do this?

I don't think that there is anything to do apart from updating the sequences, and I don't know a better way than yours.

@LaurenzAlbe Thank you! I'm also thinking about running something similar to this gist in case the primary database is not available, would this work too: https://gist.github.com/bubiche/61da7917edc14d2d2d6f14bf1662c297. I just query for the maximum value of each sequence and set the value to max_val + 1

That doesn't look good; it makes too many assumptions about the database. Perhaps it works for you. I'd just query pg_sequences and use nextval().

@LaurenzAlbe thank you! TIL
